# bash script not exiting correctly after EOF error (expecting then);

Tags: bash, eof

My following script is producing an error (it complains about expecting 'then' keyword before the file exits. I can't locate the error. Please help if you have the time.

Thank you,
Yucca

```
#!/bin/sh
#Makes the /usr/lib/jvm in case...
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm;
sudo mkdir /org-thejarbar-work-dir;
cd /org-thejarbar-work-dir;

#Update this line to reflect newer versions of JDK...
wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u1-b08/jdk-7u1-linux-i586.tar.gz;

#Extract the download
tar -xvf ./*gz;

#Move it to where it can be found...
sudo mv ./* /usr/lib/jvm/;
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1*/bin/java /usr/bin/;
sudo rm -rf /org-thejarbar-work-dir;

#Makes the /usr/lib/maven in case...
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/maven;
sudo mkdir /org-thejarbar-work-dir;
cd /org-thejarbar-work-dir;

#Update this line to reflect newer versions of maven
wget http://mirrors.powertech.no/www.apache.org/dist//maven/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.3-bin.tar.gz;
tar -xvf ./*gz;

#Move it to a more logical location
sudo mv ./* /usr/lib/maven/;

#If you have Maven on Windows and use VirtualBox, you can set up the maven to be a virtualbox shared folder.
#The name must match the name used below (ignore if irrelevant to you).
sudo mount -t vboxsf maven /usr/lib/maven;

#Link the new Maven to the bin...
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/maven/apache-maven-*/bin/mvn /usr/bin/;
sudo rm -rf /org-thejarbar-work-dir;
sudo mkdir /org-thejarbar-work-dir;
cd /org-thejarbar-work-dir;

#Update this line to reflect newer versions of Netbeans or replace 'javase' with 'javaee' or add Java EE manually via
#Netbeans 'plugins as needed.
wget http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/7.0.1/final/bundles/netbeans-7.0.1-ml-javase-linux.sh;
sh //*sh;
sudo mv ./* /usr/lib/ide/;

#Add Netbeans launcher to your PATH. Doing so allows you to run 'netbeans' command from the terminal
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/ide/netbeans-7*/bin/netbeans /usr/bin/;

#If you use VirtualBox , you can share your projects between Host and guest. Name of shared
#folder must match 'NetBeansProjects' Remove this if you don't need...
if [ ! -d "~/NetBeansProjects" ]; then
    sudo mkdir ~/NetBeansProjects;
fi

sudo mount -t vboxsf NetBeansProjects ~/NetBeansProjects;
sudo rm -rf /org-thejarbar-work-dir;
sudo mkdir /org-thejarbar-work-dir;
cd /org-thejarbar-work-dir;

#Update this line to reflect newer versions of Netbeans or replace 'javase' with 'javaee' or add Java EE manually via
#Netbeans 'plugins as needed.
wget http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/7.0.1/final/bundles/netbeans-7.0.1-ml-javase-linux.sh;
sh //*sh;
sudo mv ./* /usr/lib/ide/;

#Add Netbeans launcher to your PATH. Doing so allows you to run 'netbeans' command from the terminal
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/ide/netbeans-7*/bin/netbeans /usr/bin/;

#If you use VirtualBox , you can share your projects between Host and guest. Name of shared
#folder must match 'NetBeansProjects' Remove this if you don't need...
if [ ! -d "~/NetBeansProjects" ]; then
    sudo mkdir ~/NetBeansProjects;
fi

sudo mount -t vboxsf NetBeansProjects ~/NetBeansProjects;
sudo rm -rf /org-thejarbar-work-dir;
sudo mkdir /org-thejarbar-work-dir;
cd /org-thejarbar-work-dir;
sudo wget http://download-ln.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-11.tar.gz
sudo tar -zxvf ./*.gz;

#Move it to a better location...
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/ide/idea-IC*;
sudo mv ./* /usr/lib/ide/;

#Add IDEA launcher to your PATH. Doing so allows you to run 'idea.sh' command from the terminal
rm /usr/bin/idea.sh;
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/ide/idea-IC*/bin/idea.sh /usr/bin/;

#If you use VirtualBox , you can share your projects between Host and guest. Name of shared
#folder must match 'IdeaProjects' Remove this if you don't need...
if [ ! -d "~/IdeaProjects" ]; then
    sudo mkdir ~/IdeaProjects;
fi

sudo rm -rf /org-thejarbar-work-dir;

exit 0;
```

Note that the script works (does what is required), but the error is bothersome as I am working on sharing this script to others. I am trying to avoid the error.

Comment: Can you post your shell (i.e. the output of `ls -l /bin/sh`)? The script seems to work fine on my machine.

Comment: This will not fix your problem, but ";" are not necessary at the end of each command line. They are used if you want to execute multiple commands on the same line. I catch myself doing it as well especially right after writing code :).

Comment: @phihag Sure :) Output reads: yucca-VirtualBox:~$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2011-12-12 09:47 /bin/sh -> dash

Comment: What's in `//*sh`? That line looks like a typo, and possibly the culprit.

Comment: As an aside, you should put your temporary directory in `/tmp` (or possibly `/var/tmp`). Basic hygiene requires that it should be possible to run several instances of this script simultaneously, so use a unique temporary directory name. Even if the requirement seems theoretical, debugging that sort of problem is a nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, that's not a bash script right now - it's a bourne shell script. If you want to use bash change the first line (the "shebang") to use `/bin/bash`. You showed with your comment that `/bin/sh` is actually `dash` in your system. dash is a minimal implementation of the bourne shell.

You can debug a bash script by running it with `-x`, as in: `/bin/bash -x script.sh`; or changing the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` (temporarily).

As an aside, you're testing for directories and creating them if they don't exist. If that's all you're going to do inside the if clauses you can use a plain `mkdir -p` so it doesn't raise an error if the path already exists. Note it may not be available in all *nix systems, but it is in GNU/Linux.

Comment: would you recommend bash over bourne? I am looking to target non Mac unixes only?

Comment: If you're targetting things like Solaris, AIX and HP/UX then by all means stick to bourne. In my opinion if you're in doubt stick to bourne too, unless a bash feature would make your life easier. Note you can use `-x` with bourne too.

Comment: Bourne is more widely available, but harder to write portably and robustly. If your target platform is Linux, it's reasonable to require Bash (but document this requirement).

Comment: @tripleee - I agree with you in most of what you said, but why do you think bourne is harder to write portably? I'd say it's portable by definition.

Comment: Depends on how far backwards-portable you want to be. Old versions of SunOS, AIX, HP-UX etc had buggy `sh` implementations and atrocious userland utilities; but if you limit your target to reasonably POSIX-compliant platforms, at least you know what limits there are to work around.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `sh //*sh;` and see what scripts you have there if anything matches?
This line basically matches, and runs, any scripts ending in sh located under the `/` path.